# Selenium with Jbehave and Chromedriver hang or crash

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, jbehave

Running Selenium tests from 5 months, we encountred some majors stability problems.

Sometimes, the run looks like frozen. Neither console nor browser says anything until the story timeout.
After the story timeout, nothing else happen, following stories aren't launched.

Other times, Chrome cashes, a core dump file is generated, the story end and following ones continues.

With theses two problems, only about twenty stories among the sixty we are launching are reported, others not being executed (thanks to hangs).

We got another project for our trys, stories are smaller, fewer, and uses a more limited set of steps. Sometimes it run fine, but most of the time, same problems as our main project are encountered.

After few days of trys and research, we found nothing conclusive, it's why I came here, hopping someone got the same problem, and got some informations about it to share.

We tried to runs on multiple dockers, to reduce the charge of each vm, but we got same problems (only a dozen on a sixty of stories succed to end).

We are doing most of our runs on a centos docker under a centos vm, but same behaviour happens with windows 7 and eclipse.

We are currently using Chromedriver 2.20, Selenium 2.48.0, Jbehave 4.0.5, Jbehave web selenium 3.6-beta-2.
We tried some other versions, but nothing was better.

Our tests are launched via a jar with dependencies, and we add Ashot 1.5.2 (https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot) and extent 2.40.2 (http://relevantcodes.com/extentreports-for-selenium/)

Thanks you for your attention, I hope nothing was forgotted.

Comment: Does it work with other drivers (firefoxdriver for ex) ???

Comment: We can't try at the moment, we are waiting for new dockers to test it. Should be done before the end of week.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and tracked it down to a timing issue - when I debugged the issue didn't occur.
Setup gradle to debug the JVM where the tests run in.
An example snippet for the build.gradle file for port 5099 (instead of default 5005) is:

```
test {
    systemProperties 'jbehaveOutputDir': '../jbehave'
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    jvmArgs=["-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5099"]
}
```

Check in the report/log output exactly where the issue occurs, then add breakpoints in the section where it happens.

Apparently when things rely on each other, JBehave does not complain when you don't deal with such dependency in the steps classes.

In my example, an API call was made to create an object and the following step was executed directly after, assuming that object was there without checking, which in a docker instance apparently wasn't the case and in a local setup was.

I hope this helps anyone.